# How can I open port 22 for Sparkleshare?

Tags: networking, ssh

How can I open port 22 for Sparkleshare?

Every time I run dazzle create name_of_the_project (Sparkleshare) it gives the address but does no show the port as it should be.

Example: 
  it shows: ssh://storage@105.236.222.41:
  After (:) it should says 22, which is the port.

Why it is not showing the port? and how can I open the port in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

First check about availability of that port

```
sudo netstat -ntlup
```

the above command will list all the active listening ports.If the port number which you want is not active then you can open it.

```
lsof -i :8888
```

The above command will list the program If any application using that port 8888.If no process using that port then you can use that port . If any process using that port then you have to kill the process then only the port can be used.

to kill a process you can use command like

```
kill <pid>
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall, you may be blocking it from firewall.

First try to disable the firewall (sudo ufw disable) & check. If it works then you can allow it from firewall

Try this,
sudo ufw allow 22